# href pop up javascript isn't popping up

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup

this code isn't working.

```
<script>
    // Popup window function
        function basicPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=500,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
        }
    </script>

<?php
echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$data['_id']."' onclick='basicPopup(this.href);return false'>Edit</a></td>";
?>
```

i need a working code for an href javascript popup window. i am all out of clue.

Comment: do you get any errors? may be this new window is blocked by browser, so you could not see it

Comment: i removed all my pop up blockers. its still not working :(

Comment: put alerts or console.logs to your code to be sure it fires

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)

Comment: Go check @FelixKling's comment and this -> `<a href="javascript:basicPopup('edit.php?id=".$data['_id']."')">Edit</a>`

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo "<td><a href='javascript:basicPopup(\'edit.php?id=".$data['_id']."\')'>Edit</a></td>`

actully href overrides the onclick event of anchor tag hence  its better to write javascript inside href tag

Comment: Check if u hav blocked popup window in your browser

Comment: Just for debugging comment everything in ur basicPopup function and put a simple alert(url) and check what url u get

Answer (score 0):

Put your script in the footer.